# Fantasy Book about a boy landing in a weird afterlife

Tags: story-identification

I remember a book (all text) about a boy that died (perhaps in a train accident) and woke up in a weird afterlife.

Someone "printed" a calendar on his arm to remind him of a date when he will have to decide to either follow the weird man in what was supposed to be a paradise, or to stay in some sort of wilderness with some other people (I remember them as kind of rebel). I also remember they have a some sort of flying animals, I believe.

I think that in the end he choose to stay with the people and just fly around. Perhaps there is a sort of magic that allows him to see what happened on Earth when he flies with the animal... With this specific animal, he will dive in a sort of infinite ravine, where he fly into the cloud, to see what's happening on earth, until the animal is too tired. The boy is alway trying to get deeper into the ravine.

In my memories, the whole story happend on flying island, but honestly it could be my mind tricking me.

I read this book around 2010 in France, I don't know if it have been translated from or to English, and I don't think it's a saga, only a single book.

Comment: Is the book all in text, or was it a graphic novel?

Comment: It was all text, I guess I should add it to the main post ? Still new to this

Comment: Not an answer, but the title could apply to countless manga in the Isseki genre which has gained popularity in the last several years.

Comment: @AbL: Yes, in general, you should any necessary clarifications into the question itself; comments may end up being cleaned up, so any important information should be included in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found it, it's a book called "49 jours" by Fabrice Colin, it only came out in France I believe. Turn out there is a second volume.
It was indeed a sort of countdown of 49 days, there is some sort of dragons and a ravine, but no sign of floating island, that was some mind trickeries. [image: cover of the book "49 jours"]

Comment: You can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark in about 2 days.

Comment: You may also want to edit your answer to include any relevant details from the book that match the remembered details you included in your question. That way, the Q&A will be more helpful to others in the future.